# Face maps between simplices: why do we insert $0$ instead of $1$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, simplex

I have some confusion regarding the following lecture note by Gereon Quick   [here](https://folk.ntnu.no/gereonq/MA3403H2018/MA3403_Lecture03.pdf). The complete set of notes can be found [here](https://folk.ntnu.no/gereonq/MA3403_Lecture_Notes.pdf).

It is written that

> The standard simplices are related by face maps for $0 \le i \le n$ which can described as $\phi_i^n(t_0, \dots ,t_{n-1}) = (t_0, \dots, t_{i-1}, 0, t_i, \dots, t_{n-1})$ with the $0$ inserted at the $i^{\text{th}}$ coordinate ($t_0$ is the $0^{\text{th}}$ coordinate).

**My thinking** : I think $0$ is not inserted at the $i^{\text{th}}$ coordinate, it's inserted between the $(i-1)^{\text{st}}$ and the $i^{\text{th}}$ coordinates. I know that $(t_0,\dots,t_{i-1},0,t_i,\dots,t_{n-1}) \in \Delta^{n-1}$.

**My question** :I'm not getting why $0$ is inserted at the $i^{\text{th}}$ coordinate. Why isn't $1$ inserted at the $i^{\text{th}}$ coordinate instead?

Comment: If you insert $1$, does the point belong to the $n$-simplex?

Comment: I think  yes  @MichaelAlbanese   take $t_0=....=t_{n-1}=0\implies  t_0+t_1 +t_2+....+1.+...+t_{n-1}=1$

Comment: The point $(0, \dots, 0)$ is not in $\Delta^{n-1}$.

Comment: Why would that work?  The $t_i$'s you just chose don't live on a simplex to begin with.

Comment: Also, draw a picture in dimension 2.  The idea of the face map is geometrically sensible and will tell you why $0$ and not $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, $0$ is inserted in the $i^{\text{th}}$ coordinate of the point in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ (numbering from $0$). The fact that $t_{i-1}$ is the previous coordinate, and $t_i$ is the next coordinate is irrelevant: the subscripts refer to the coordinates of the point in $\Delta^{n-1}$, not $\Delta^n$. Said another way $$(t_0, \dots, t_{i-1}, 0, t_i, \dots, t_{n-1}) = (x_0, \dots, x_{i-1}, x_i, x_{i+1}, \dots, x_n)$$ with $x_0 = t_0, \dots, x_{i-1} = t_{i-1}, x_i = 0, x_{i+1} = t_i, \dots, x_n = t_{n-1}$, so $0$ is in the $i^{\text{th}}$ coordinate (because $x_i = 0$).

As $(t_0, \dots, t_{n-1}) \in \Delta^{n-1}$, we have $t_0 + \dots + t_{n-1} = 1$, so $(t_0, \dots, t_{i-1}, 1, t_i, \dots, t_{n-1}) \not\in \Delta^n$ because $t_0 + \dots + t_{i-1} + 1 + t_i + \dots + t_{n-1} = 2 \neq 1$. On the other hand, $(t_0, \dots, t_{i-1}, 0, t_i, \dots, t_{n-1}) \in \Delta^n$. Moreover, the set of such points actually constitutes a face of $\Delta^n$. For example, when $n = 2$, the regular $2$-simplex $\Delta^2$ is the intersection of the affine plane $x + y + z = 1$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the octant $x, y, z \geq 0$. In particular, $\Delta^2$ is a triangle (image taken from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex#The_standard_simplex)).

$\hspace{66mm}$[image]

The three sides of the triangle correspond to the images of the three face maps $\phi^2_0$, $\phi^2_1$, and $\phi^2_2$. Namely, the image of $\phi^2_0$ is the edge in the $yz$-plane, the image of $\phi^2_1$ is the edge in the $xz$-plane, and the image of $\phi^2_2$ is the edge in the $xy$-plane.